# Generate routes and views based on one RoR database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies for a very newbie question, but I've spent the last couple weeks trying to figure this out in my spare time.  Figured I'd see whether brighter minds might be able to help.

The idea:

- I have a RoR database with State, City, and some information
- I would like to build one view for State and one view for City
- And have routes automatically point to ".com/state/city" or ".com/state"

How do I go about:

1. Creating automatic routes based on this database, vs hard coding
   individual routes?
2. Creating one view for City and one view for
   State?

Thanks and apologies if this is a very stupid question. :)

Edit: Also, any example apps in Github would be awesome.

Comment: *Creating automatic routes based on this database* How?

Comment: Using SQL terminology, creating a macro to generate routes based on the database (eg, one route for each city), as opposed to manually typing up each route in routes.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Msencenb that hard coding them in the route file would not be the way to go. However a route that is /:state/:city will match anything with 2 parts if you are not careful since it is very generic (like was mentioned).

You could use something like [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). The example it uses right at the top of the README is actually states.

From README:

```
With FriendlyId, it's easy to make your application use URLs like:

http://example.com/states/washington
instead of:

http://example.com/states/4323454
```

Then you could make a route for your city like:

```
http://example.com/states/minnesota/city/minneapolis
```

Comment: This is the option I ended up following. For anyone curious, this is what the routes.rb ended up looking like, using Friendly_ID:

    get ':id', to: 'state#show', as: 'state'
    get ':state_id/:id', to: 'city#show', as: 'city'

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend hard coding these into the routes file, regardless of whether you are using some sort of code generation or not. Rails allows for generic route matching. For example:

```
get '/:state', to: 'states#show'
get '/:state/:city', to: 'city#show'
```

Note: This is an awfully generic match, so make sure your routes file is in the right order so it doesn't also grab other specific routes.